# Distribution of points in a 2d grid that minimize the average distance from all the other points of the grid to these points

Tags: matlab, distance, optimal

Let's consider a 2d array A with `A(i,j)=0` whatever i and j initially.
Let's now add n points for which `A(i,j)=1`, i.e., `sum(sum(A))=n`

The question is:

What is the optimal spatial distribution of these n points that would minimize the average Euclidean distance map of 0 to 1.

with Matlab that would be:

```
A=zeros(10,10) % a grid of 10 by 10, only 0s
A(1:2)=1;
A(2,3)=1; 
A(4,3)=1; 
A(5,5)=1; %a guess: assign n=4 pixels to 1 

dmap = bwdist(A) % Calculate Euclidean distance map (shortest distance from 0 to 1)
dmap(dmap==0)=[]; % Remove 0 distance (e.g., from A(5,5) to A(5,5))
average_min_distance_from_0_to_1 = mean(dmap)
```

So I want to find the optimal point distribution (i.e., this line `A(1:2)=1; A(2,3)=1; A(4,3)=1; A(5,5)=1`) so that `average_min_distance_from_0_to_1`  is the minimum among all the possible permutations.

I think it may be a variation of the geometric median problem ([The point that minimizes the sum of euclidean distances to a set of n points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57277247/the-point-that-minimizes-the-sum-of-euclidean-distances-to-a-set-of-n-points)), but in my case I try to find the optimal distribution of more than 1 point.

Thanks for any help.
Best.

Comment: your problem has not a unique answer and it is an optimization problem, consider using genetic algorithm in matlab (which seems the best option in case of your problem)

Comment: Hello Hadi. Thanks for your answer. Genetic algorithm was indeed the good choice. I did not know about it and found a simple explanation of the method there: https://towardsdatascience.com/introduction-to-genetic-algorithms-including-example-code-e396e98d8bf3. It was enough to build a simple algorithm that solved my problem. Thanks for the indication.